# Understanding Universal Coefficient Proof: why $H_2(D\otimes G)\simeq\mathrm{Tor}_2[H_{n-1}(C),G]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm trying to understand the 3 affirmations that come after the line

**"According (2.8) and (2.6) we have"**

I think these are propositions that apply to the exact sequence:

$$0 \to  Z_n(C)\otimes G \to  C_n\otimes G \to  Z_{n-1}(C)\otimes G \to  0$$

Here is the proof and following, the 2 propositions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So... Why the 3 affirmations hold? None of them seems obvious to me.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the source to know more context and what is covered previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are working in the category of Abelian groups,
where the $\text{Tor}_2$ functor vanishes. According to the author
(who?), the complex 
$$\cdots\to0\to0\to Z_n(C)\to C_n\to Z_{n-1}(C)\tag{1}$$
is a projective resolution of $H_{n-1}(C)$. That is, the modules
within are projective (free Abelian groups) and that there's a map
from $Z_{n-1}(C)$ to $H_{n-1}(C)$ such that
$$0\to Z_n(C)\to C_n\to Z_{n-1}(C)\to H_{n-1}(C)\to0$$
is exact.
We can compute Tor-groups $\text{Tor}_*(H_{n-1}(C),G)$
 by tensoring the projective resolution
$(1)$ with $G$ and computing homology. The tensored sequence is
$$\cdots\to0\to0\to Z_n(C)\otimes G\to C_n\otimes G\to Z_{n-1}(C)
\otimes G\tag{2}\to0.$$

The homology of $(2)$ at the $Z_n(C)\otimes G$ term is $\text{Tor}_2(H_{n-1}(C),G)
=0$. That is the kernel of $e\otimes i$.

The homology of $(2)$ at the $C_n\otimes G$ term is $\text{Tor}_1(H_{n-1}(C),G)
=\text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(C),G)$. That is the kernel of $d\otimes i$
factored by the image of $e\otimes i$.

The homology of $(2)$ at the $Z_{n-1}(C)\otimes G$ term is $\text{Tor}_0(H_{n-1}(C),G)
=H_{n-1}(C)\otimes G$. That is the cokernel of $d\otimes i$.

Comment: How are you counting the index of the Tor? Is from right to left?

Comment: Also, the author is Tsen-Hu, the book is "Introduction to Homological Algebra"

Comment: Why, for example, the homology of (2) at $Z_n(C)\otimes G$ is $Tor_2(H_{n-1}(C),G)$? Where did the $H_{n-1}$ came from?

Comment: Why the first quotient gives only kernel? And why the second gives cokernel?

Comment: The homology of a complex is kernel factored by image. At $Z_n(C)\otimes G$ the map going in is the zero map, so the image you factor out by is zero, so the homology is just a kernel etc.